# Is there a way to update user inputted text in Firestore flutter without using a dialog box?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dialog

Im trying to retrieve and update data in flutter Firestore but all the tutorials I've seen use some sort of a dialog box. I wanted to know if there was another function/method to retrieve and update user inputted data.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You can just use a button to get the text from textfield and then pass the text to firestore. Just like what you do with a dialog box.

Comment: So can I take my Firestore data to a new route using this?

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. Yes, you can do that too. Just pass data as arguments to your new route. Check the link out its really easy
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data